# Read more / Read less functionality failing

Tags: javascript, zepto

I'm using the following code to automatically shorten `div` elements that contain a lot of text. It abbreviates the first paragraph and adds a "Read More" link. This works fine, as does the "Read less" link, which appears after the content is expanded. However, the "Read More" link does not work the second time it is clicked.

Is there a JavaScript error that could be causing this problem in the code below? (Tested on mobile safari, iOS simulator.)

```
function ExpandableContent(container, userSettings) {

        /************ Validation *************/ 

        if (!this.constructor || !this.constructor instanceof ExpandableContent) {
            return new ExpandableContent(container, userSettings); 
        }
        if (typeof container !== 'object') {
            console.error("Must provide DOM element.");
            return; 
        }
        if (!container.find('p').first().length) {
            console.error("Containing element must include at least one paragraph element.");
            return;
        }

        /************ Process user-provided settings *************/ 

        var settings = {
            previewLen: 75,
            readMoreClass: 'read-more', 
            readLessClass: 'read-less',
            readMoreText: 'Read More >', 
            readLessText: '< Read Less', 
            ellipsis: true
        };

        // Any property can be overridden by adding a data attribute to the container
        for (var prop in settings) {
            if (userSettings && prop in userSettings) settings[prop] = userSettings[prop]; 
            if (typeof container.data(prop) !== 'undefined') settings[prop] = container.data(prop); 
        }

        /************ Initialization *************/ 

        var containerOrig, para1, para1Orig, bottomBuffer, readMore, readLess;

        function init() {
            readMore = $("<a href='javascript:undefined;'></a>").addClass(settings.readMoreClass), 
            readLess = $("<a href='javascript:undefined;'></a>").addClass(settings.readLessClass); 

            readMore.text(settings.readMoreText); 
            readLess.text(settings.readLessText); 

            // Store the original state of the container
            containerOrig = (function(o) {
                return {
                    height: o.height, 
                    top: o.top
                };
            })(container.offset()),

            // Store the original state of the container's first paragraph if it exists
            para1 = container.find('p').first();

            para1Orig = (function(para1, o) {
                return {
                    content: para1.html(), 
                    height: o.height, 
                    top: o.top
                };
            })(para1, para1.offset()); 

            // Shortened divs will be extended by the pixel equivalent of 1rem to make room for CSS borders.
            bottomBuffer = getFontSizeAsPixels($('h1'));
        }

        init(); 
        hide(); 

        /************ Public hide, show and text abbreviation methods *************/ 

        function show(){ 
            readMore.remove(); 

            // Show all elements after paragraph 1
            elementsAfterPara1().map(function(el) { $(el).show(); }); 

            // Restore height of container and its 1st paragraph
            para1.html( para1Orig.content ).removeClass('abbreviated'); 
            container.removeClass('abbreviated').css('height', containerOrig.height); 

            // Generate 'Read less' link 
            container.append(readLess); 
            readLess.click(function(){
                hide(); 
                scrollToEl(container);
            }); 
        }

        function abbreviate(text) {
            if (text.length <= settings.previewLen) return text; // Nothing to abbreviate
            text = text.substr(0, settings.previewLen); 
            if (settings.ellipsis === true) text+= '...';
            return text; 
        }

        function elementsAfterPara1() {
            var result = [], children = container.children(), start = children.index(para1) + 1; 
            if (!children[start]) return; // nothing to hide

            for (var i = start, l = children.length; i < l; i++)
                result.push(children[i]); 

            return result; 
        }

        function hide(){
            // Remove 'Read Less' if such a link is leftover from a previous request
            readLess.remove(); 

            // Get abbreviated text for first paragraph
            var abbrev = abbreviate(para1Orig.content);

            // abbreviate the first paragraph, shortening the text and appending an '...' if necessary
            para1.html(abbrev); 

            //Shorten the container so it's just tall enough to encompass paragraph 1
            var containerNewHeight = (para1Orig.top - containerOrig.top) + para1.offset().height;

            // Hide everything after the first paragraph
            elementsAfterPara1().map(function(el) { $(el).hide(); }); 

            // Setting overflow-y to hidden prevents the user from scrolling the abbreviated div
            container.addClass('abbreviated').css('height', containerNewHeight).css('overflow-y','hidden'); 

            // Prevent the user from scrolling internally through the DIV
            container.on('touchmove', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }); 

            //Generate a 'Read More' link and place it below the text
            para1.append(readMore); 
            readMore.on('tap click', show); 
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can think of is that line: `readMore.on('tap click', show);`

Are you sure that 'tap click' (with space) is the correct event?

Why don't you stick to the

```
readMore.click(function(){
            ... 
        });
```

you used in the show function?